# Nginx try_files fallback path returns 404 when using url query args

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

## Goal

I have a folder `/assets` which contains files like `index.hml`, `css/*`, `js/*`, etc.

Here is what I want to accomplish:

- `/` or `index.html` server `index.html`
- Try to try to a serve static file (`css/main.css`, etc)
- If above fails, 404

I also need query params (`$args`) to be passed through

Here is my enginx partial configuration:

```
location / {
  root /assets;
  try_files $uri $uri/index.html$is_args$args =404;
}
```

With this settings I get the following results:

- `domain.com/css/main.css` > `200: domain.com/css/main.css`
- `domain.com/index.html` > `200: domain.com/index.html`
- `domain.com/` > `200: (renders same as  domain.com/index.html)`
- `domain.com/index.html?q=x` > `200: domain.com/index.html?q=x`
- `domain.com/?q=x` > `404: Not Found`

#### Question

What do I have to change to have `domain.com/?q=x` to return the same response as `domain.com/index.html?q=x` instead of not 404

Comment: Try: `root /assets; index index.html; try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposed answer by @richard-smith solved it

```
location / {
  root /assets;
   index index.html;
   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```